# How can I draw the value text for a slider widget from matplotlib?

Tags: python, slider, matplotlib

I'm using a slider widget from matplotlib and I've been trying to update just the slider bar using blit for faster animation because if I use draw() for the whole canvas it is too slow.  I got the bar to animate faster using this method (though it doesn't look perfect), but I can't figure out how to draw the slider value that shows up next to the slider.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  My code for the slider is something like this:

```
import pylab as p
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

axsigma  = p.axes([0.25, 0.10, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor) 
slider1 = Slider (axsigma, 'Sigma',0.20, 18,  valinit=s0,dragging=True,  fc='blue')

canvas1=axsigma.figure.canvas

def update (val):
    canvas1.blit(axsigma.bbox)

slider1.on_changed(update)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly (win7 64bit mpl 1.0.0 py2.6.5) with:

```
In [7]: f = figure()
In [8]: ax = f.add_subplot(111)
In [9]: sl = Slider (ax, 'Sigma',0.20, 18, valinit=0, dragging=True,  fc='blue')
```

it can be dragged manually very fast and without needing to make draw() or canvas.blit().

Comment: mmm, I think that's only for updating the slider value when it's not being changed by it's direct use.  I think the problem is that the slider value text is a figure text object, so the only way to render the text is to render the whole figure, which is exactly what I don't want to do.  Now I removed the value text from the slider and I'm thinking about setting some axes text with the slider value, but I can't figure out how to draw only the axes text.  Thanks anyway though.